# Is there a way to determine if libuv is experiencing thread starvation?

Tags: node.js, multithreading, libuv

In node.js, the environment variable "UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE" (default=4) sets the number of threads libuv will use to essentially make synchronous I/O calls asynchronous. As has been mentioned elsewhere, this has nothing to do with the number of CPU cores, etc. The challenge is that if an application has so much of this I/O going on, other seemingly unrelated calls can also get blocked (this too has been mentioned elsewhere), which makes for some very difficult troubleshooting. To that end, I want to "detect" if/when libuv is experiencing thread starvation (i.e. all "UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE" threads are in-use, waiting for I/O). I've not been able to find anything. Is libuv thread usage logged anywhere or can it otherwise be monitored?